# React.js: Trouble awaiting nested function at top level of funcitonal component

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I added the `async` keyword ahead of my app's parent component in order to await a nested async method but it has caused several errors in Chrome's browser console:

```
const AdminArea = async props => {
  <few elements removed...> 

  if ( process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' &&
    process.env.REACT_APP_WP_USER &&
    process.env.REACT_APP_WP_PASSWORD
  ) {
    const authentication = new Authentication();
    const token = await authentication.validateJwtOrCreateAndSaveToCookie({
        username : process.env.REACT_APP_WP_USER
    , password : process.env.REACT_APP_WP_PASSWORD
    });
  }

  <continues...>


// chrome errors
adminArea.bundle.js:64647 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in AdminArea
    at invariant (http://localhost:8080/shared/adminArea.bundle.js:64647:15)
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType (http://localhost:8080/shared/adminArea.bundle.js:76425:5)
    at reconcileChildFibers (http://localhost:8080/shared/adminArea.bundle.js:77199:7)
    at reconcileChildren (http://localhost:8080/shared/adminArea.bundle.js:78994:28)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent 

adminArea.bundle.js:64647 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in AdminArea
    at invariant (http://localhost:8080/shared/adminArea.bundle.js:64647:15)
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType (http://localhost:8080/shared/adminArea.bundle.js:76425:5)
    at reconcileChildFibers (http://localhost:8080/shared/adminArea.bundle.js:77199:7)
    at reconcileChildren (http://localhost:8080/shared/adminArea.bundle.js:78994:28)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:8080/shared/adminArea.bundle.js:79656:5)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:8080/shared/adminArea.bundle.js:80217:16)
```

If React functional components can not be async how should the nested async function be `awaited` ? I can see in my debugger it's assigned variable holds a pending promise past the point where it already should have resolved.

Comment: You're supposed to use hooks like `useEffect` to fetch data and do other async work.

Comment: @JJJ good to know. I'll test it out now

Comment: In addition to @JJJ 's comment: an `async` function always returns a `Promise` (no matter you `await` on anything or not). In your case it's what's returned not the actual data

Comment: just replace `await` with Promise-based statement like `.then()`. Anyway I agree that hooks are typically better place to handle async, but for different reason - you just don't want to send request on each re-render